# Underscore between pictures in html

Tags: html

I am trying to put multiple icons (pictures) in one line, and when I do that, I get underscores between each picture.

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Facebook" src="Facebook.png"> </a> 
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Youtube" src="Youtube.png"> </a> 
<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Twitter" src="Twitter.png"> </a> 
<a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Instagram" src="Instagram.png"> </a>
```

And this is how does it look like

[image]

See attached picture, notice the underscores between each picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your spaces between `<a>` tags and `<img>` tags.

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="Facebook.png"></a> 
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Youtube" src="Youtube.png"></a> 
<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" src="Twitter.png"></a> 
<a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Instagram" src="Instagram.png"></a>
```

Browser considers you are in a *link* string, even if there is an image. So it will underline the link as usual.

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Facebook" src="Facebook.png"> </a> 
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Youtube" src="Youtube.png"> </a> 
<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Twitter" src="Twitter.png"> </a> 
<a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="Instagram" src="Instagram.png"> </a>
```

Comment: Nice :) Notice that every char in a `<a>` tag will be underlined by default

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after the `img` tag within a `tag` which treated as a character and in default `a` tag has the underline(CSS `text-decoration` property).

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="Facebook.png"></a>
<!--                                              -^-                                    -^-   -->
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Youtube" src="Youtube.png"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Twit11ter" src="Twitter.png"></a>
<a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Instagram" src="Instagram.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```